# No module named 'datasets.utils.download_manager'

Tags: python, module, opensuse, python-3.10, huggingface-datasets

So I installed the `evaluate` package:

```
(env) bscuser@localhost:~/Documents> pip show evaluate
Name: evaluate
Version: 0.1.1
Summary: HuggingFace community-driven open-source library of evaluation
Home-page: https://github.com/huggingface/evaluate
Author: HuggingFace Inc.
Author-email: leandro@huggingface.co
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/bscuser/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: datasets, dill, fsspec, huggingface-hub, multiprocess, numpy, packaging, pandas, requests, responses, tqdm, xxhash
Required-by:
```

But then when I import it in `comettest.py`:

```
import evaluate

prediction = ["The relationship between cats and dogs is not exactly friendly."]
reference = [["The relationship between dogs and cats is not exactly friendly."]]

chrf = evaluate.load("chrf")
results = chrf.compute(predictions=prediction, references=reference)
print(results)
```

I get the following error:

```
(env) bscuser@localhost:~/Documents> python comettest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bscuser/Documents/comettest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import evaluate
  File "/home/bscuser/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/evaluate/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .evaluator import Evaluator, TextClassificationEvaluator, evaluator
  File "/home/bscuser/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/evaluate/evaluator.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .loading import load
  File "/home/bscuser/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/evaluate/loading.py", line 32, in <module>
    from datasets.utils.download_manager import DownloadMode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets.utils.download_manager'
```

I'm using Python 3.10.5, on an OpenSUSE Leap 15.3.

Comment: Does the `evaluate` package have installation instructions in the documentation? Did you follow them? If yes, it looks like an error in the `evaluate` package. I'd suggest reporting to them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you import this library as such

```
from datasets import load_dataset
```

https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.13.0/how_to.html